# How to summary calculate in devexpress report

Tags: devexpress, report

Ihave a report and the report has different value positive or negative then I want to calculate like that positive values are gathered themselves and negative values are gathered themselves. for example 10,20 =30 and -10-20=-30

Answer (score 0):

You can use event SummaryRowChanged and set manually your logic:

```
    public double PositiveSumm = 0;
    public double NegativeSumm = 0;
    private void xrTableCell1_SummaryRowChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var currentVal = Convert.ToDouble(GetCurrentColumnValue("ColumnName"));
        if (currentVal > 0)
        {
            PositivSumm += currentVal;
        }
        else
        {
            NegativSumm += currentVal;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Mustafa Mark answer as solution if it helped you